# Rate of change calculus

Tags: calculus

Temperature affects the amount of electricity used to run the heater. The amount you run the heater affects the monthly bill. Find the rate of increase of the bill if the temperature is 8 degrees.

$E(T)=\frac{5T+100}{T+2}$ where $E$ is the energy in kJ and $T$ is the temperature in °C.

$B(E)= 3 + 0.2E$ where B is the monthly bill.

I am confused as to what to do as there are 2 different equations here. Would I make them equal each other or not? I am confused. Can someone please help me solve this question? What would the solution look like?

Comment: The question is about the rate of change of $B$, with respect to $T$. But at a first glance, it seems like $B$ is not a function of $T$. But $B$ is a function of $E$, which in turn is a function of $T$. Therefore, when $T$ changes, so does $B$, and $B$ actually **is** a function of $T$. In order to find the rate of change of $B$, you need to think of $B$ as a composition of two function and then use the chain rule.

Comment: You want $\frac{dE}{dT}$, the rate of change of the Bill with respect to Temperature. Can you use the chain rule to express that in terms of two rates you can calculate?

Answer (score 1):

Express $B$ in terms of $T$:

$$
B(T)= 3 + 0.2\left(\frac{5T+100}{T+2}\right)
$$

Find the derivative function which is going to be your rate function:

$$
B'(T)=0+0.2\frac{5(T+2)-(5T+100)}{(T+2)^2}=-\frac{18}{(T+2)^2}
$$

Evaluate it at $T=8$:

$$
B'(8)=-0.18\ monetary\ units\ per\ one\ unit\ of\ temperature
$$

This means that as you're generating more heat, you're paying less. In other words, your monthly bill goes down as you're using more heat. At least, that's what follows from the formulas or I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

Comment: of course you are spending less if the *external temperature* rises.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $E=\frac{5(T+20)}{T+2}$ and $B=3+\frac E5$, what is $B$ in terms of $T$?

Once you've got that, just evaluate $\frac{dB}{dT}$ at $T=8$.